# Why calling a webservice from ajax throws internal server 500 error?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I using ajax $.post method to send data to my .asmx webservice but it throws internal server 500 error.

.asmx.cs

```
namespace WebServices
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Summary description for himher
  /// </summary>
  [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
  [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
  [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
  // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
  [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
  public class himher : System.Web.Services.WebService
  {
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    //[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
    public string InsertUsers(string name, string pwd)
    {
      basicoperation bop = new basicoperation();
      return bop.insertUsers(name, pwd);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
function save() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.post("http://localhost:8373/himher.asmx?op=InsertUsers", {
      name: "testing ajax name", 
      pwd: "testing ajax pwd"
    }, function(data, status) {
      alert(data);
    });
  });
}
```

I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

I have also added an extension to chrome such as `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin`.

I have spent a lot of time on it and it's nowhere near getting fixed. Help me on this. I am a newbie to AJAX.

And yes I have tested the web service and it's working perfectly such as sending data to the SQL table. No error on C#'s end. It throws no exception.

I tried running it on IIS express and windows IIS and both return same error. Help.

Update: insertusers

```
 public string insertUsers(string Name, string Password)
        {
                string status;

                String ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString;

                SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConStr);    // to make a connection with DB 

                SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("InsertUsers", sqlCon); // now in order to perform action such as insert SP, we must create command object which needs command name and conncetion only

                sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  // you must tell the system that insertInfo is a storedprocedure 

                SqlParameter sqlParamName = new SqlParameter("@UserName", Name);
                SqlParameter sqlParamPwd= new SqlParameter("@Password", Password);

                sqlCom.Parameters.Add(sqlParamName);
                sqlCom.Parameters.Add(sqlParamPwd);      

                try
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();

                    sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();   // executenonquery is used for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 

                    //sqlCom.ExecuteScalar();   // used to pick or read a single value from procedure
                   // Response.Write("Done");

                    sqlCon.Close();

                    status= "Success";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //response.Write(ex.Message);
                    status = ex.Message;
                }
            return status;
        }
```

stack trace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.MoveToContent()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocolHelper.GetRequestElement()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap12ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean&amp; abortProcessing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the webservice to see what line of code throws the error? Or inspecting the console to see the error message? Or putting a try/catch around the code to see what the exception is? Your assertion about JS code being the culprit is false as a 500 error message will only be generated from the server.

Comment: Error is server side. So one of the two lines you have there is most probably throwing an exception.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: the code is absolutely fine. Becuase I tested it running and inserting code into my db using it and it works like a charm

Comment: So where is the 500 coming from?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan solved, it was a javascript problem as i said. So i was right, yeahhhh.

Comment: Well I assumed you at least had the common sense to double check you had the correct settings in JS.

Comment: see it was a JS problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I figured it out and it was for sure a javascript problem.

The only things needed to be done was to remove **?** from url such as

```
"http://localhost:8373/himher.asmx/InsertUsers",
```

instead of

```
"http://localhost:8373/himher.asmx?op=InsertUsers"
```